# Vs Code, pylance stops for no reason

Tags: visual-studio-code, crash, pylance

It starts and stops all the time.Highlighting and autocompletes goes missing.
I think something is forcing it to stop, then it autostarts again.

- I reinstalled VScode a few times, tried reinstalling extensions.
- Preferences-settings-extensions-python-> 'Language server' is 'Pylance'.
- Python path is okay.

I use python 3.9.10 / VsCode 1.6.3.2 x64

If you can give me some advice, it will be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: I installed vscode.ZIP and now 'pylance' runs fine